# Recomendation for cloud provider for a personal use VPC

Tags: cloud-service, cloud-computing

I need a decent linux server for personal use. Personal user = host a `data base` on the server (so that I don't have to create it both on my laptop and school computer), host some toy websites, and generally have a backup computer in the cloud.

I see `AWS Lightsail` and `Gougle Compute Engine` seem to be the thing I am looking for. Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please see: [Are questions for service providers welcome at our site?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2713/185) Also: [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/) is also a competitor in this field, and they do offer Linux hosting. (If you want to host Windows, the license is included on Azure servers.)